# AUGraph variSpeed didn't accept StreamFormat on iOS 5.x

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, audio, core-audio

I have a AUGraph to Play and Record Audio with this Setup:

```
RemoteIO      ->                                 -> RemoteIO
                  Mulichannel Mixer -> variSpeed 
Read Callback ->                                 -> Write Callback
```

My Problem is that the kAudioUnitSubType_Varispeed didn't accept the StreamFormat on iOS 5.x. On iOS 6 is works. Without the correct StreamFormat the AUGraph didn't run.

I set the same StreamFormat on all In- and Outputs:

```
    memset(&_audioFormat, 0, sizeof(_audioFormat));
UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription);
CheckError(AudioUnitGetProperty(self.io, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 0, &_audioFormat, &propertySize), "Couldn't get audio Format for io input");
_audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame  = 1;
_audioFormat.mSampleRate = self.hardwareSampleRate;

// set audio Format for io
CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty(self.io, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output, kInputBus, &_audioFormat, sizeof(_audioFormat)), "Couldn't set audio Format for output");
CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty(self.io, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Input, kOutputBus, &_audioFormat, sizeof(_audioFormat)), "Couldn't set audio Format for input");

// set audio Format for mixer
CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty(self.mixer, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 0, &_audioFormat, sizeof(_audioFormat)), "Couldn't set audio Format for mixer 0");
CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty(self.mixer, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 1, &_audioFormat, sizeof(_audioFormat)), "Couldn't set audio Format for mixer 1");
CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty(self.mixer, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output, kOutputBus, &_audioFormat, sizeof(_audioFormat)), "Couldn't set audio Format for mixer output");

// set audio Format for speed
CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty(self.speed, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 0, &_audioFormat, sizeof(_audioFormat)), "Couldn't set audio Format for speed input");
CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty(self.speed, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 0, &_audioFormat, sizeof(_audioFormat)), "Couldn't set audio Format for speed output");
```

CAShow on iOS 5.x:

```
    AudioUnitGraph 0x6CC000:
  Member Nodes:
    node 1: 'auou' 'rioc' 'appl', instance 0x18cc2a0 O I
    node 2: 'aumx' 'mcmx' 'appl', instance 0x455680 O I
    node 3: 'aufc' 'vari' 'appl', instance 0x450270 O I
  Connections:
    node   1 bus   1 => node   2 bus   1  [ 1 ch,  22000 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]
    node   2 bus   0 => node   3 bus   0  [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]
    node   3 bus   0 => node   1 bus   0  [ 1 ch,  22000 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]
  Input Callbacks:
    {0x53b5d, 0x454cd0} => node   2 bus   0  [1 ch, 22000 Hz]
  CurrentState:
    mLastUpdateError=0, eventsToProcess=F, isRunning=F
```

CAShow on iOS 6.x:

```
    AudioUnitGraph 0x388000:
  Member Nodes:
    node 1: 'auou' 'rioc' 'appl', instance 0x1f03b1e0 O I
    node 2: 'aumx' 'mcmx' 'appl', instance 0x1f05fd60 O I
    node 3: 'aufc' 'vari' 'appl', instance 0x1e590b90 O I
  Connections:
    node   1 bus   1 => node   2 bus   1  [ 1 ch,  22000 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]
    node   2 bus   0 => node   3 bus   0  [ 1 ch,  22000 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]
    node   3 bus   0 => node   1 bus   0  [ 1 ch,  22000 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]
  Input Callbacks:
    {0xe9b5d, 0x1e58e4e0} => node   2 bus   0  [1 ch, 22000 Hz]
  CurrentState:
    mLastUpdateError=0, eventsToProcess=F, isRunning=F
```

Why does the speed Node didn't accept the StreamFormat on iOS 5.x :( ?
Is there anyone out there who can help me?
Thanks.

Comment: It looks like a good place to start would be to get rid of the sample rate conversion on 5.x. In that graph, your varispeed takes in 44100 Hz audio and puts out 22000 Hz audio. This is likely not something it's actually capable of doing. Try setting the varispeed's input to 22000 Hz instead.

Comment: self.hardwareSampleRate is set to 22000 Hz...